# how to change the defaut menu icon to image icon in ionic

Tags: html, angularjs, image, ionic-framework

I'm trying to replace the menu icon to image icon in ionic application.
I have a menu.html as follows:

```
<ion-side-menus>
<ion-side-menu-content>
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-dark nav-title-slide-ios7">
</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-nav-view name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
 </ion-side-menu-content>

<ion-side-menu side="left">
<header class="bar bar-header bar-dark">
 </header>
  <ion-content class="has-header">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="app.home">
      Home
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="app.profile">
      Update Profile
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="app.project">
     Add Project
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item menu-close ng-click="logout();">
      Log Out
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
</ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

But I don't know how to replace the menu icon with image icon. can you please help

this is home.html:

```
 <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
 <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
 </ion-nav-buttons>
 <icon-view>
 <ion-pane>
 <ion-content>
 </ion-content>
 </ion-pane>
 </icon-view>
```

Answer (score 18):

For Ionic 4+, just wrap your image icon with

```
<ion-menu-toggle>
    <img src='your-src'>
</ion-menu-toggle>
```

Answer (score 11):

> In Ionic 4 just use the below code inside your template

```html
<ion-buttons slot="start"> <ion-menu-button> <img src='../../assets/icon/favicon.png'> </ion-menu-button> </ion-buttons>
```

Comment: This should be the excepted answer. Does not override anything but works as expected.

Answer (score 6):

As of Ionic 5, you can just add any other `ion-icon` inside of the `ion-menu-button` like this:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button>
        <ion-icon color="success" name="close"></ion-icon> // <--- here
      </ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

And in the same way, you can also use a custom SVG icon:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button>
        <ion-icon 
          color="success" 
          src="assets/my-icons/custom-menu.svg" // <--- like this
        ></ion-icon>
      </ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: Or you can use <ion-icon :icon="close" />

Answer (score 0):

replace `button` and the `navicon` class with an `image` tag

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
 <img src="img/myImage.jpg" class="button button-icon button-clear" menu-toggle="left">
 </ion-nav-buttons>
 <icon-view>
 <ion-pane>
 <ion-content>
 </ion-content>
 </ion-pane>
 </icon-view>
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9rxqrb3x/)

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the menu icon's css globally in *app.scss* by adding the below css and the menu icon on your assets folder.

```
ion-icon[name='menu']:before {
  content: url('../assets/icon/menu.png');
}
```

Comment: how about in ionic 4?

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert your image into an svg file using a tool like this: 
[image converter](https://www.pngtosvg.com/)

once you have your SVG file, follow this steps:

1. slightly modify the build config to add new icons to the ionicons library, and 
   use them anywhere.
2. Create a new folder in your project to store your custom icons, i.e. src/assets/custom-ion-icons.
3. Modify angular.json. Find this section:

"assets":

```
[
  {
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "src/assets",
    "output": "assets"
  },
  {
    "glob": "**/*.svg",
    "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/dist/ionic/svg",
    "output": "./svg"
  }
]
```

4. See how it's packaging all the svg files from the ionic library into "./svg"? Those are the default icons. Whenever you use one of the default icons, your app finds it in that output directory. We can add our own icons to that directory. Add one more object to the "assets" array, so it looks like this:

"assets":

```
[
  {
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "src/assets",
    "output": "assets"
  },
  {
    "glob": "**/*.svg",
    "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/dist/ionic/svg",
    "output": "./svg"
  },
  {
    "glob": "**/*.svg",
    "input": "src/assets/custom-ion-icons",
    "output": "./svg"
  }
]
```

5. For each new icon, create two files (one for iOS, one for android/material-design). The following would create a new icon named "newicon":
   src/assets/custom-ion-icons/ios-newicon.svg
   src/assets/custom-ion-icons/md-newicon.svg
   The svg image should consist of shapes with black fills. Strokes won't always show up, depending on the context.
6. And finally modify your app.module.ts file, in order to set the default ion-menu-button icon like this:

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot({
      menuIcon: 'newicon'
    }),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  ...
})
```

in the case of this example we should have two files ios-newicon.svg and md-newicon.svg

Hope this helps.

References:

[how to add custom svgs to ionic project](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionicons/issues/589#issuecomment-417812752)

[ionic config options](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/config)